# Design: using a backend server to circumvent great firewall of china

Tags: angularjs, google-docs, firewall

I have a front-end angular app using firebase to store user data.

I currently do not have a backend set up, such as a node.js server.

I would like to use the Google Docs API to upload files from my app.

Since the Great Firewall of China does not (or makes unstable) the use of Google services, is it possible to place those services on the backend server and still use them reliably?

Perhaps after they have uploaded the document to firebase, a backend script retrieves it, uploads it to google docs, and then removes the record from firebase? Just trying to see if Google or similar services are even feasible for this use case.

I suppose the crux of my question is whether or not the calling of the Google API would be taking place on the user's computer, in which case would it become unstable?

** Updates for clarity:

I am deciding whether my firebase-backed app needs a more traditional backend like a node server to do things like: upload images and documents, send mail via Mandrill, etc... It would be helpful to me if I knew whether, after putting in the time to create a server, some of the services I am after (aka APIs) are any more resilient to the GFW than they would be if they ran on the client side. So if any one has had success in such a task, I would like to know.

** Technical update:

So, for example, if I run the Google Maps API on the client side, if the user is in China and is not running a VPN, accessing the API calls will either lag or time out or (rarely) success in returning the scripts. If I was somehow able to able to process the map query "off-site" aka on the server, could I then return with a static image of the map to a Chinese user without fail?

Comment: I would vote to close this question because it's so unclear what is being asked, but because there is a bounty, I cannot. Still, even with the bounty, it's going to be difficult to get good answers because of the low quality of the question. Compguy24, take some time to edit the question to make it clearer and more specific. Otherwise, a "yes, no, maybe" answer would fit, but not help you.

Comment: @Mogsdad made an edit

Comment: I hope that does help you find an answerer. It does give more background about your motivation for the question, but still doesn't address the technical aspects of your concern, which sounds quite broad. If you can think of any further improvements, don't hesitate to add them. Good luck to you!

Comment: Vote up because you are trying to circumvent the great wall of China

Comment: If you are making only small calls to the Google API, why can't you just route that traffic through a VPN (probably one that you set up) to get around it? Also, @rollingBalls answer seems useful.

Comment: I have the same problem. I want to use firebase, but it seems totally blocked in China by GFW. if firebase url is only an HTTP protocol, maybe a reverse proxy will help.

Answer (score 3):

> If I was somehow able to able to process the map query "off-site" aka
>   on the server, could I then return with a static image of the map to a
>   Chinese user without fail?

Yes, of course. What you are going to miss this way is all the front-end interactive functionality Google Maps offers. But if that's ok in your use case, sure.

I have never tried it with the GCF, but what I would do is this:

`Google Maps <-> Your Reverse proxy <-> User`

So, instead of the user visitng the real google maps site, it will be visiting your maps.mydomain.com site, that will be sitting in between, proxying everything.

`Nginx` is an excellent choice for a reverse proxy. If you need more control, there are good node.js reverse proxying packages that you an use to rewrite the content extensively before serving it (perhaps to obfuscate it in case the GCF blacklists content based on pattern matching, or to change the script names/links again to avoid pattern matching).

Answer (score 1):

You are misunderstanding about the great firewall of China.  I consulted for a couple of Chinese companies after the dot com crash so I can say this from personal experience, not hearsay. 
It is mostly high-end Cisco hardware behind gateways behind their government telecom infrastructure.  Nowadays they knock off what hardware they can, every chance they can, and spend money on specialized hardware to monitor cell phones systems.
There was a brief mention of the street-level surveillance hardware on 20/20 before the crash if you are interested in looking it up. 
Not to discourage you, but I say set up whatever open servers you want with whatever frontends or backends you want, but the reality is the traffic is not going to be there.

That is why they call it an oppressive regime, they do not get to decide for themselves, remember?